# how faster way convert datatable to list and display in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, datatable, oledb

Dear All Master,

how faster way convert datatable to list  and display in datagridview in vb.net?.

maybe an easy way so I can turn the datatable into a list

please recommend the best solution.

Thanks

```
  Public Sub fillDataGridView1()
            Try
                dt = New DataTable
                Dim query As String = "SELECT NOD,ITM,CIA,DPR,QTY FROM RSD WHERE QTY > 0 AND PNM=@PNM"
                Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
                    Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                        Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                            da.Fill(dt)
                            da.Dispose()
 Dim totalColumn As New DataColumn()
                            totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                            totalColumn.ColumnName = "Total"
                            totalColumn.Expression = "[CIA]*[QTY]*(1-[DPR]/100)"
                            dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn)
grid.DataSource = dt
 Me.grid.Refresh()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
 Private Sub PopulateComboBox()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM RSD UNION SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM RSG ORDER BY PNM"
            Try
                dt = New DataTable
                Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
                    Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
                        'Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        'Insert the Default Item to DataTable.
                        Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                        row(0) = ""
                        dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
                        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
                        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "PNM"
                        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "PNM"
 End Using
                End Using
            Catch myerror As OleDbException
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
            Finally
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need a list? What's the problem with just binding the `DataTable` itself?

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Do you really need a list?` yes I need from datatable to list  and `What's the problem with just binding the DataTable itself?` because I want to use the winform library which is Kimtoo.BindingProvider. So I can bind datagridview but the library can only be if I make it a list then I want to convert datatable to list

Comment: There's no magic solution. If you want a list then it has to be a list of something. Where's your something? Have you defined a class that represents a record, just as the examples in `BindingNavigator` documentation shows? Once you know what you're making a list of, then you can write code to create those things. Have you made any effort to read the data from a row in the table and push it into an instance of your type? It would appear not. It seems like you want someone else to provide code for you to copy and paste without you applying any of the principles of C# programming.

Comment: @user09938 , if indeed the delivery of my words offended you then I apologize

Comment: If you need you data in a List, why even load it into a datatable in the first place?  Just load it straight into your required List(of YouCustomDataModelType) using a data reader object instead of tableAdapters.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create a structure thar represents your data :

```
Structure MyDataStruc
        dim NOD as integer
        dim ITM as integer
        dim CIA as integer
        dim DPR as integer
        dim QTY as integer
        dim total as integer
    End Structure
```

after that create a list of that structure

```
Dim dataList As new List(Of MyDataStruc)
```

you can then enumerate your datatable to fill list :

```
for each row as dataRow in dt.rows
 dim myData as new MyDataStruc
  mydata.NOD=row(0)  'or row("NOD")
  mydata.ITM=row(1)
  mydata.CIA=row(2)
  mydata.DPR=row(3)
  mydata.QTY=row(4)
  mydata.total=row(2) * row(4) * (1-row(3)/100)
  
  dataList.add(myData)
next
```

Adapt this snippet to your requirements and dataTypes.